# How do I use a delegate other than ToString to show an object's value while debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, tostring

.NET/Visual Studio uses an object's ToString() method to display the value of an object when viewing it in the debugger. I would like to display specific information, but since .ToString() is often used by the framework when converting an object to a string, I cannot do it by overriding ToString(). Is there an attribute I can use to tell the debugger to use a different method or property?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`*<sup>[[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx)</sup>*. You supply it with a format string that references fields/properties within the class to display while debugging without having to mess with `ToString()`.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {count}")]
class MyHashtable
{
    public int count = 4;
}
```

It also works with methods:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{ToDebugString()}")]
public class SomeClass
{
    public override String ToString()
    {
        return "Normal ToString()";
    }

    public String ToDebugString()
    {
        return "ToDebugString()";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Awesome, I saw that attribute in Intellisense but I didn't realize the value could be tokenized. This makes much more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Requires `using System.Diagnostics;`